# how to display first row data's of excel sheet in userform automatically when clicking on a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of 4 rows of data, i need to make the first row data's visible automatically in userform excel using vb , when i click on the button in ribbon. Later by clicking on next row it needs to display the complete data's of next row.

for example,

```
stud_id       stud_name      age          gender
 1                a          20            M
 2                b          22            M
 3                c          25            F
 4                d          22            F
```

```vb
Public ncurretnrow As Long

Sub Userform_Initialize()
ncurrentrow = Sheet3("2017").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
traversedata (ncurrentrow)

End Sub


Public Sub traversedata(nrow As Long)

Me.stud_id.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 1).Value
Me.stud_name.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 2).Value
Me.age.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 2).Value
If Optionyes = True Then
    Me.genderm.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 3).Value
Else
    Me.genderf.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 3).Value
End If
```

Comment: Is this `VBA` or `vb.net` ? you have noth tags in your post. Another question, do you want that every time you click on a certain row that it will open a User_form and display the cuurent row's values in the form ?

Comment: it is vba, yes i want the first row to display in userform automatically whenever i click on that button.

Comment: you want it to display first row data ? or the row where your cursor is located ?

Comment: complete first row data in active worksheet needs to be displayed in userform

Answer (score 0):

See code below (both `Sub`s inside the User_Form module).

```
Public ws As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim HeaderRng As Range
Dim ncurretnrow As Long

' set the worksheet object
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017")

Set HeaderRng = ws.Cells.Find(what:="stud_id") ' look for the header (below it you will find the first row with data)
If Not HeaderRng Is Nothing Then
    ncurretnrow = HeaderRng.Row + 1
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to find stud_id header", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

traversedata ncurretnrow

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub traversedata(nrow As Long)

With Me
    .stud_id.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 1).Value
    .stud_name.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 2).Value
    .age.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 3).Value
    If Optionyes = True Then
        .genderm.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 4).Value
    Else
        .genderf.Value = ws.Cells(nrow, 4).Value
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: why the ncurrentrow is not updated when i increment                   
    Private Sub nextrow_clickbutton_Click()

    Do
    ncurrentrow = ncurrentrow + 1
    traversedata (ncurrentrow)
    Loop Until ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ncurrentrow, 1).Value = 
    ""

    End Sub